# Corpus français (modernes et historiques) / Modern and older French corpora

Tags: grammaire, ressources

La mention par Gilles du [corpus français de l'université de Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ws_fra/), dont j'ignorais l'existence, me fait poser cette question : quels sont les corpus ([corpora ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1182)) français accessibles en ligne, qui couvrent soit le français moderne (disons, sources des 15 dernières années), soit le français historique ?

Et, question bonnus, existe-t-il des corpus [« grammaticalement étiquetés »](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tiquetage_grammatical), comme on peut en trouver [en anglais et en allemand](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/).

Comment: Juste un détail, mais les versions française et anglaise de ton sujet ne demandent pas la même chose. Tu définis apparemment le français "historique" comme tout français datant de plus d'une quinzaine d'années... Comme tu le sais certainement, ce que l'on appelle "Middle French" en anglais est la langue "française" médiévale ("Moyen français")... qui n'a pas grand chose à voir avec le français contemporain...

Comment: @Dave: oui, en fait, je voulais *old French* mais pas *Old French*… mais mon choix n'était pas heureux. J'ai corrigé, merci !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Les corpus ESLO](http://eslo.tge-adonis.fr) (Enquête socio-linguistique orléanaise) 1 et 2, aussi connu sous le nom de corpus d'Orléans est le plus grand corpus de français oral. Il est transcrit et partiellement étiqueté. La version 1 date des années 60, la version 2 des environs de 2010.
- En ce qui concerne les travaux sur les parties du discours le [French Treebank](http://www.llf.cnrs.fr/Gens/Abeille/French-Treebank-fr.php) de l'équipe d'Anne Abeillé est la référence.
- [Le corpus Frantext](http://www.frantext.fr/) de l'Atilf est un corpus de français écrit de référence.
- [Le corpus Scientext](http://scientext.msh-alpes.fr/scientext-site/spip.php?article9) est son équivalent pour les langages spécialisés, il est également disponible en anglais.

Comment: Hum, j'imagine le nombre d'heures passées à transcrire par des esclaves, hum, pardon, des étudiants orléanais…

Comment: @F'x: Et à coder des outils d'étiquetage ;)