# Quel est le pluriel français de « corpus »?

Tags: pluriel, latin

Les dictionnaires que j'ai pu consulter (Littré, TLFi) ne donnent aucun pluriel à *corpus*, ce qui laisse supposer soit que le pluriel n'est pas usité, soit qu'il est régulier (*corpus*). L'anglais donne à *corpus* deux pluriels, le pluriel latin *corpora* et le pluriel natif *corpuses*. Quel est donc le pluriel français de *corpus* ?

Je vous donne le début de mes recherches : la [concordance ATILF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/concordance/corpora) ne donne pas d'usage de *corpora* en français (tous les résultats sont des textes latins), et aucun des [résultats](http://www.cnrtl.fr/concordance/corpus) de *corpus* (par ailleurs peu nombreux) ne correspond à un pluriel. Face à cette impasse je me suis arrêté, démuni.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour tous les emprunts, le pluriel régulier du français (ajout de `-s` sauf aux mots qui se terminent par `-s`, `-x` ou `-z`) est admissible. Voir « [Which words in -us get their plural in -i?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/441/which-words-in-us-get-their-plural-in-i) ». Donc *des corpus* est correct.¹

S'agissant en particulier du pluriel *corpus*, on peut voir sur d'autres corpus que celui que tu as regardé que *des corpus* est bien la seule forme couramment usitée (pour le terme linguistique).

[un corpus,des corpus,des corpora http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=un%20corpus%2Cdes%20corpus%2Cdes%20corpora&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=un+corpus%2Cdes+corpus%2Cdes+corpora&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Les [occurences de `des corpora`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22des%20corpora%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr) correspondent quasiment toutes à des usages en biologie, dans des locutions où *corpus* est suivi d'un qualificatif aussi en latin (*corpora allata*, *corpora cardiaca*, ...).

Sur [le corpus de l'Université de Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/ws_fra/), on ne trouve que [8 occurences de corpora](http://wortschatz.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-fra/fra_mixed/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=32044914) contre [3776 de corpus](http://wortschatz.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-fra/fra_mixed/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=715183) avec plusieurs voisins de gauche bien placés indiquant un pluriel (*des*, *grands*, *différents*, ...). Il y a bien un exemple de *corpora* utilisé par un linguiste, mais c'est une rareté.

¹ 
<sub>Et je dirais bien que le pluriel de `/œ̃kɔʁpys/` est `/dekɔʁpys/` et celui de `/œ̃koɾpus/` est `/dekoɾpoɾa/`.</sub>

Comment: +1 pour avoir fait des recherches particulières :·) (Je replussoierais pour ¹, mais ça veut pas.)

Answer (score 5):

Je n'ai pas fait de recherches particulière. Le fond est le même que pour [Which words in -us get their plural in -i?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/441/which-words-in-us-get-their-plural-in-i) où la conclusion était que pour les mots empruntés, le pluriel d'origine et un pluriel francisé coexistent et plus le mot est courant, plus le pluriel d'origine est ressenti comme inutilement pédant.  J'utiliserais donc *corpus* sans hésiter.

Ce que fait le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/corpus/) où on trouve en fin de page (c'est moi qui souligne)

> L'annotation réalisée porte sur 4 910 descriptions définies. Le schéma est basé sur une classification fine qui contraste en particulier, avec les classifications très générales, parfois binaires, **des corpus annotés** existants tels que (Fraurud 90). Les catégories de base du schéma sont les suivantes : description autonome, description coréférentielle, description associative, description situationnelle, description non référentielle.

Comment: +1 Tous les linguistes francophones que je connais utilisent *corpus* pour le pluriel.

Comment: Tous les linguistes francophones que je connais aussi, mais ça tient plus au nombre de linguistes francophones que je connais.